# Does shaming architecture or talking badly about a home for sale online through online images cause hezek re’iya?

Tags: shulchan-aruch

Shulchan Aruch – It is forbidden to stare at another’s property in a case where this could damage it. Does online images count?

Comment: Where does Shulchan Aruch say that?

Comment: Admur Nizkei Mamon 11; Rama 154/3; Michaber 357/1 “Hezek Reiyah”; Tur 157; Rosh Baba Basra 1; Baba Basra 2b 

[Smeh 378/4] This applies even if there is no worry of Ayin Hara as a result of this looking. If however there is worry that looking into the property will cause an Ayin Hara, then it is certainly forbidden to look into the property as doing so will cause it damage. [Admur ibid; Michaber 378/5; Baba Metiza 107a; Baba Basra 2b See Smeh 378/4 that the Ayin Hara itself causes damage]

Comment: Please edit the tur, siman, and seif (if relevant) into your post, otherwise it is a baseless assertion (even if Sh"A does say this. I have definitely not learned Choshen Mishpat inside, so I wouldn't be able to say)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I don't know how, I'm new and a beginner.

Comment: Click [edit] to edit your post.

Comment: I don't see how looking at a picture could be היזק ראייה, but posting negative commentary about a property, particularly with no תועלת, could well be לשון הרע/רכילות.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.